# Use global gradle install with Buildship

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, buildship

I want to create a Gradle project in Eclipse using Buildship. When I create it, the IDE tries to download Gradle 2.9 from somewhere.

But I have a system-wide install of Gradle 2.12 (installed by pacman).

How can I convince Buildship to use my local Gradle installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prematurely clicked finish. One should click next and specify (in my case)

```
/usr/share/java/gradle
```

as the local installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

Add inside build.gradle this:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.12'
}
```

Or run the wrapper task with the argument -gradle-version 2.12 (to add this right click on the wrapper task, in the Gradle Tasks view of Eclipse.

Finally run the following tasks: clean, wrapper, build. Ensure that inside the project root directory, the ./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file contains the following line:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-bin.zip
```

Otherwise substitute/insert it and rerun gradle clean, wrapper, build.